# Pod is not visible

Tags: git, kubernetes, tcp, flux, gitops

I followed [Kubecon Seattle 2018 Gitops Tutorial](https://github.com/bricef/gitops-tutorial)
  everything was working fine till 4th step,
but in 5th step `podinfo pod` is not visible.

watch kubectl get pods

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS       RESTARTS AGE     
flux-cb9449876-mr477                            1/1     Running        0     130m    
memcached-57b897cc4-qdm9s                       1/1     Running        0     112m    
nginx-ingress-default-backend-c5449fb44-4hdsk   1/1     Running        0     117m
```

Output of " kubectl get svc "

```
NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
kubernetes                      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP     55d
memcached                       ClusterIP   None           <none>        11211/TCP   3h8m
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP   10.96.38.220   <none>        80/TCP      32d
```

podinfo is not available

Then I looked up in log

`kubectl logs deploy/flux -n default -f`

```
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:36.823063265Z caller=main.go:243 version=1.14.2
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:36.823163934Z caller=main.go:372 msg="using in cluster config to connect to the cluster"
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:36.855773345Z caller=main.go:457 component=cluster identity=/etc/fluxd/ssh/identity
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:36.855844999Z caller=main.go:458 component=cluster identity.pub="ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDmURfuENXm4nFDeqLxPdWIlR5mxP/iuZvkAJP24+qBnXklLOW8tTSem3gWsXHiUqNYoz2H2GtnxYtE0tbC7hm2whx7sINsYScRZtbvbnbssJOOQVtqet9H8FA6mYNsB9T5OfC6z2P1XEK7meCOpyWFoX1wwfP2U7dp3B1vyilJ3m8Ye/pGp7Cc+JvDQA2h/QnHbnPmJuYSHs70viYGMMQf+iVMF8hUCcHGu+KBBmwHkuWxHnsJGgvK1ogyhTaFBnNA1uS6vZ0YWwG/YUvBDRdJweERH4GjU/r00GFrKRc4VdQtP9gZ0BeeCb/5BQI9Mv2KAtY/CMbW43XqIXIrJtFF"
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:36.855878612Z caller=main.go:463 host=https://10.96.0.1:443 version=kubernetes-v1.19.4
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:36.855945167Z caller=main.go:475 kubectl=/usr/local/bin/kubectl
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:36.857475549Z caller=main.go:487 ping=true
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.860632128Z caller=memcached.go:74 component=memcached err="Error setting memcache servers to 'memcached': lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:46398->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.860715996Z caller=main.go:623 url=git@github.com:adamya21/flux-get-started user="Weave Flux" email=support@weave.works signing-key= verify-signatures=false sync-tag=flux-sync state=git readonly=false notes-ref=flux set-author=false git-secret=false
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.860752394Z caller=main.go:724 upstream="no upstream URL given"
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.860846781Z caller=main.go:753 metrics-addr=:3031
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.861358341Z caller=loop.go:100 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git repo has not been cloned yet"
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.861387235Z caller=images.go:17 component=sync-loop msg="polling for new images for automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.861397564Z caller=images.go:27 component=sync-loop msg="no automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:34:41.865215548Z caller=main.go:745 addr=:3030
ts=2021-01-15T08:35:01.919748924Z caller=checkpoint.go:17 component=checkpoint err="Get https://checkpoint-api.weave.works/v1/check/weave-flux?arch=amd64&flag_cluster-version=kubernetes-v1.19.4&flag_git-configured=true&flag_kernel-version=3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64&os=linux&signature=b616J%2FpWxkgLWhu2NhuEYNaTZMLW56FVIh0AMl3CsXw%3D&version=1.14.2: dial tcp: lookup checkpoint-api.weave.works on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:41764->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:35:12.049527657Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: context deadline exceeded"
ts=2021-01-15T08:35:32.054751173Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:44141->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:35:51.869490983Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:37208->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:36:02.055842273Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: context deadline exceeded"
ts=2021-01-15T08:36:22.062247221Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:58701->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:36:37.065694566Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:56255->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:36:51.86884923Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:34696->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:37:07.066591466Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: context deadline exceeded"
ts=2021-01-15T08:37:22.071783513Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:50783->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:37:47.255162253Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51041->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:37:51.868880178Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:53053->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:38:07.261358033Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51588->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:38:22.266596926Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:45953->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:38:47.271634599Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:39224->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:38:51.869713463Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:55573->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:39:07.278346046Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:58529->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:39:27.284635089Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:38726->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:39:41.862114925Z caller=loop.go:100 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/flux-gitclone668030573'...\nssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Try again\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
ts=2021-01-15T08:39:41.862170208Z caller=images.go:17 component=sync-loop msg="polling for new images for automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:39:41.862181078Z caller=images.go:27 component=sync-loop msg="no automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:39:51.868216785Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:33252->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:39:52.291631976Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51894->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:40:12.45973175Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51750->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:40:32.466746085Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:39214->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:40:51.867193019Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:34552->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:40:57.471825512Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51462->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:41:17.480755902Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:41731->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:41:37.485738783Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:35485->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:41:51.869570177Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:53611->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:42:02.492761138Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:54251->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:42:22.500097314Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:35717->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:42:37.7075323Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:34092->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:42:51.869000022Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:60617->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:43:07.70982334Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: context deadline exceeded"
ts=2021-01-15T08:43:22.715332273Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:55661->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:43:47.721153845Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:53155->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:43:51.868371209Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:38345->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:44:07.725666709Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:54325->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:44:27.731810955Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:40385->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:44:41.862497835Z caller=loop.go:100 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/flux-gitclone840919681'...\nssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Try again\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
ts=2021-01-15T08:44:41.862587482Z caller=images.go:17 component=sync-loop msg="polling for new images for automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:44:41.862600887Z caller=images.go:27 component=sync-loop msg="no automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:44:51.868365853Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:55180->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:44:52.739621384Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:57758->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:45:12.950133572Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:54777->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:45:32.954843685Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:35571->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:45:52.961057124Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:56311->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:45:56.869193985Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:37618->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:46:12.967348301Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:55825->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:46:32.973536104Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:45545->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:46:56.868726966Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:45892->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:46:57.981027132Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:40489->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:47:17.986703183Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:48203->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:47:38.155044126Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:42154->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:47:51.868894269Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51534->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:48:03.160403195Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:35888->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:48:23.165321296Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51039->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:48:38.169858629Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:34557->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:48:51.870002998Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:57020->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:08.170398368Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: context deadline exceeded"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:08.176751205Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:54320->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:23.181095889Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:52173->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:41.863283527Z caller=loop.go:100 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/flux-gitclone961961173'...\nssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Try again\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:41.863399735Z caller=images.go:17 component=sync-loop msg="polling for new images for automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:41.863413661Z caller=images.go:27 component=sync-loop msg="no automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:43.352663841Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:58389->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:49:56.869838102Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:36917->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:50:08.359806772Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:55293->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:50:23.364739403Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:37486->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:50:43.369517581Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:54391->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:50:56.869860958Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:37425->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:51:08.374763101Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:33253->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:51:23.381632821Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:54799->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:51:43.391650301Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:45664->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:51:56.922228566Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:39847->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:52:08.577116075Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:34241->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:52:23.583223599Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:46500->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:52:48.589070754Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:45452->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:52:56.870406732Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:45356->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:53:08.598299259Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:49505->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:53:28.603596415Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:48330->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:53:53.611489439Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:56748->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:53:56.868358268Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:45665->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:54:13.61821865Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:36012->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:54:33.77844023Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=quay.io/coreos/flannel auth={map[]} err="Get https://quay.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup quay.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:51428->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:54:41.864143047Z caller=loop.go:100 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/flux-gitclone112489833'...\nssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Try again\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
ts=2021-01-15T08:54:41.864242844Z caller=images.go:17 component=sync-loop msg="polling for new images for automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:54:41.86426189Z caller=images.go:27 component=sync-loop msg="no automated workloads"
ts=2021-01-15T08:54:56.8692891Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:60678->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:54:58.785614576Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/cronjob-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:55230->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:55:18.792003267Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/function-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:46652->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:55:38.797160671Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/kubeless/http-trigger-controller auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:54356->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:55:56.869788329Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:39315->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:56:03.804094799Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:37297->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:56:23.808771074Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/library/memcached auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:52093->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:56:38.813264438Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:48563->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
ts=2021-01-15T08:56:56.869490937Z caller=memcached.go:156 component=memcached err="error updating memcache servers: lookup _memcached._tcp.memcached on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.244.0.144:46779->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"
ts=2021-01-15T08:57:08.958860392Z caller=warming.go:154 component=warmer canonical_name=index.docker.io/fluxcd/flux auth={map[]} err="Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: context deadline exceeded"
```

So what is causing the exact problem? Is it because of connection refused as per logs?

Comment: Looks like the repo was not ready yet. Have you tried to wait a bit more for the operator to react to the changes?

Comment: It's been more than 4 hours now

Answer (score 1):

As already noticed the error you see means that there is a problem with the DNS configuration in your Cluster. In order to debug it I recommend using [Debugging DNS Resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/):

> This page provides hints on diagnosing DNS problems.

There you will find several things to check in order to narrow down the issue. These includes:

- [Check the local DNS configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-the-local-dns-configuration-first)
- [Check if the DNS pod is running](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-if-the-dns-pod-is-running)
- [Check for errors in the DNS pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-for-errors-in-the-dns-pod)
- [Check if DNS service is up](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#is-dns-service-up)
- [Are DNS endpoints exposed?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#are-dns-endpoints-exposed)
- [Are DNS queries being received/processed?](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#are-dns-queries-being-received-processed)
- and the [Known issues](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues)

Sometimes it's just the matter of restarting the coredns deployment:

```
kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart deployment coredns
```

Or [installing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) it fresh.

Comment: I changed reinstalled everything as the error was due to some dns configuration error .Thnakyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Could not resolve hostname github.com - check your dns configuration

Comment: cat resolv.conf  :    ```; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
search localdomain
nameserver 192.168.48.2 ```

Comment: Enable dns addon

Comment: kubectl get po -n kube-system , Kube dns addon is not visible so how can i check if it's just disable or not present

Comment: If you are using minikube then `minikube addons list` and you will see if kube-dns is enabled

Comment: I'm not using minikube

Comment: etcd-master-node , kube-apiserver-master-node, kube-controller-manager-master-node,kube-flannel-ds-2p6rn ,kube-flannel-ds-wtvz4, kube-proxy-h997g, kube-proxy-kzz9z, kube-scheduler-master-node. there is no core dns running